# The type or namespace name X could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, time, visual-studio-2015, timing

I want to make a metronome app.

I've searched about it and I gave this code from this website:
http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/c-metronome-with-timers-and-beeps/

```
Using System.Threading;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    timer.Interval += 1000;

    timer.Start();
    Console.ReadLine();
    timer.Stop();
}

static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.Beep(4000, 100);
}
```

I get two errors:

> no overload for 'timer_Elapsed' matches delegate 'ElapsedEventHandler'
>
> The type or namespace name 'ElapsedEventArgs' could not be found

Comment: static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
or add using System.Timers and remove all `System.Timers.` prefxes.

Comment: @lexx9999 That seems to be the correct answer. Why not post an answer?

Comment: Parsa Jeihoun and @lexx999, I wouldn't recommend putting namespaces like System.Timers, System.Drawing.Color, et al. unless you absolutely have to or if there are no other classes or libraries other than System....*. Doing so can create problems if you are using similar objects or properties from other namespaces. Using pointers on the other hand would be okay if it's for short term like in instance methods.

Comment: to Matt, it was just too simple.
@Sometowngeek, for this simple program I don't expect conflicts. Matt was just following the linked example.

Comment: On a side note, if you need precise timing, consider using [multimedia timers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5501/The-Multimedia-Timer-for-the-NET-Framework).

Comment: As the author of the article in question, I just wanted to point out that it does (briefly) mention the confusion between timer classes, using the System.Timers namespace, and how to resolve conflicts. The code quoted above is just the final code of the article, but one should read it in its entirety.

Answer (score 2):

At the top of your .cs file add `using System.Timers;` 
Or change your second method to

```
static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.Beep(4000, 100);
}
```

It's functionally the same either way, but better to add the `using`.
The issue is that you're specifying the `System.Timer` namespace for the `Timer` class but not for `ElapsedEventArgs`, so the compiler doesn't recognize `ElapsedEventArgs`.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
Using System.Threading;
```

to

```
using System.Timers;
```

See a working <kbd>[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LprPFc)</kbd>.